# Error en Android Studio, Failed to resolve junit:junit:4.12

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un error a la hora de importar un proyecto en Android a otro ordenador. He estado trabajando en este proyecto durante casi un mes y no me ha dado problemas, pero me he visto obligado a cambiarme de ordenador. Después de instalar Android Studio en el nuevo ordenador e importar el proyecto, me salen los siguientes mensajes de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de mi fichero `app/build.gradle` es el siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tigestion.guillermo.agendagui"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Y el código de `build.gradle` general:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

He mirado tutoriales tanto en youtube como en este foro, en español y en Inglés, y no me sirve ninguna solución. No me sirve comentar la línea testCompile, no me sirve añadir:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}
```

No me sirve descargar un fichero junit 4-12.jar y añadirlo manualmente a la estructura del proyecto borrando el junit anterior y ya no se que más hacer porque básicamente esas son todas las soluciones que he encontrado.

Ambas configuraciones de Android (Tanto la del ordenador antiguo como en el nuevo) son las que deja por defecto la instalación. El sistema operativo en el anterior era Windows 7 y en el nuevo Windows 8.

Por favor ayuda.

Comment: Esta no es la solución que estás buscando, además no se cuentas clases y xmls puedas llegar a tener pero a mi también me pasó algo parecido y en el peor de los cosas te creas un nuevo proyecto y accediendo a la carpeta 'app' de tu proyecto antiguo vas pegando manualmente los xmls y clases poco a poco en el nuevo.

Comment: Al crear un nuevo proyecto me salen automáticamente los mismos errores sin yo tocar nada, es por eso que quiero resolver este error

Comment: En el archivo `build.gradle` (el que está fuera de las carpetas), si lo pones así debería funcionar: `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }` Y luego: `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}`

Comment: Nada, sigue sin funcionar, da los mismos errores.

Comment: Compara tus dos archivos `gradle` con lo que te puse en la respuesta.

Comment: En este hilo hablan de tu mismo problema, échale un ojo a ver si te sirve y te soluciona algo

Comment: ¿Que hilo? @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: se me olvidó poner el enlace sorry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519219/error23-17-failed-to-resolve-junitjunit4-12

Comment: Ese es uno de los primeros enlaces que vi, no me funciona. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Vale, no cómo ha pasado, pero esta mañana al encender el ordenador para ver si podía arreglarlo de golpe ha funcionado todo. No lo entiendo, pero gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo tengo configurado así:

### a). `build.gradle` (el que está fuera de las carpetas)

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
                    jcenter() 
                    mavenCentral() 
                 }
```

En ese mismo archivo:

```
allprojects { 
     repositories { 
                    jcenter() 
                  } 
}
```

### b). `build.gradle` dentro de la carpeta `app`

Pongo sólo lo relativo a JUnit... lo demás no lo cambies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Nada, los mismos errores. Tengo puesto lo mismo que tu en los dos ficheros en los puntos que me dijiste, y salen los mismos errores.

Comment: @G.Corporales ¿podrías [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/110091/edit) poniendo cómo tienes los dos archivos `gradle`?

Comment: Ya lo he editado, pero hasta que no lo revisen no se cambiará, aún no tengo los permisos suficientes.

Comment: Tenías que editar tu pregunta, no mi respuesta... Bueno, no importa.

Comment: La configuración parece correcta. En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913562/5587982) apuntan a un problema con el SDK, en ese caso, estaba apuntando a una versión de 32bytes, cuando el Windows era de 64bytes. Se explica cómo verificarlo. Suena a un problema de ese tipo.

Comment: He seguido los pasos de esa respuesta y nada. He reinstalado el Android Studio y la jdk de Java y nada. ¿Alguna otra posible solución? Y gracias de antemano por el tiempo que te estas tomando.

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a ir a Build->clean build y cuando termine de procesar Build->Rebuild ?

En ocasiones Android Studio se cuelga por cualquier archivo temporal creado o por distintas cuestiones inexplicables...

Comment: Si, y no hace nada

Comment: Entonces dale a "show in file" y mira en que linea te da errores para poder darte más detalles.